# Smartphone app with Wordfeud-like time constraints

Tags: software

In Wordfeud, it's kind of play-and-forget. When your opponent makes a move, you get a notification. Typically I would move once a day while commuting to and from work. A game would typically take a week to finish.

I'm used to playing chess on the eboard FICS client.

However, I haven't found a way to utilise the FICS network to play in this more casual way. It seems that if you disconnect, you defeat. Even if you didn't, you wouldn't get any notifications. I've played on a few websites, where you get an email, but it doesn't really exploit the bells-and-whistles of the smartphone.

**So, could you recommend me a client that would do the above?**

A smartphone friendly (responsive) website with email notifications is also interesting as a second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also worth considering [Chesspresso](http://www.chesspresso.net/) and [Chess Time](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haptic.chesstime&hl=en) which are quite popular among casual "don't care about my rating" players who might be intimidated by the **higher** average playing strength on chess.com

Comment: I tried Chesspresso and it is close to perfect.
It does take some time to adjust to the timemodel with at least one whole day for each move.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something called [Correspondence Chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_chess) where you can make moves at your leisure in a time frame you're comfortable with. Chess.com and Chess Time both provide smartphone apps with this capability. Chess.com has many more features and Chess Time only provides correspondence.

[iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chess.com-play-learn-chess/id329218549?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chess&hl=en) for Chess.com 
[iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chess-time-multiplayer-game/id455602152?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haptic.chesstime&hl=en) for Chess Time

Comment: Thanks for providing the right term, that was key! I tried Chess.com, but it only seems to have real-time matches. Chess Time works as intended but the UX is not very sleek.

Comment: No problem - on chess.com, it's called "Online Chess." You can set the waiting time for games.